# Directed edges from one set to another

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a directed graph $G(V, E)$ and set of nodes `A`. I'm interested to find a set of edges going from `A` to `V-A`.

```
  g1 = Graph[
  DirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 4}, {1, 9}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 9}, {3, 
 2}, {3, 6}, {3, 7}, {3, 9}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 
 9}, {5, 6}, {5, 9}, {6, 3}, {6, 4}, {6, 5}, {6, 9}, {7, 3}, {7, 
 4}, {7, 9}, {8, 1}, {8, 2}, {8, 3}, {8, 4}, {8, 5}, {8, 6}, {8, 
 7}}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
 A = {8, 3, 6, 5, 7};
 (*V-A={1, 4, 9, 2}*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Complement[VertexOutComponent[g1, A], A]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 9}

```
EdgeList[g1, DirectedEdge[ Alternatives @@ A, 
   Alternatives @@ Complement[VertexOutComponent[g1, A], A]]]
```

> {3 -> 2, 3 -> 9, 5 -> 9, 6 -> 4, 6 -> 9, 7 -> 4, 7 -> 9, 8 -> 1, 
>    8 -> 2, 8 -> 4}